# How can I update a state with an array inside an object?

Tags: reactjs, events, state

this is the state I want to update

```
 inputData: {
      id: '',
      inputArr: ['']
    }
```

Im generating inputs from my state

```
 inner = arr.input.map((inputs, index) => {
        return (
          <li key={index}>
            <label>{inputs.inputLabel}</label>
            <input
              name={index}
              //value={inputs.inputValue}
              type={inputs.inputType}
              onChange={this.handleChangeInp}
            />
          </li>
```

how should I use my hanldeChangeInp to grab the input and push it to the inputArr,

this is what I did so far:

```
 handleChangeInp = e => {
    const index = Number(e.target.name)
    const inputData = this.state.inputData.inputArr.map((ing, i) => {
      i == index ? e.target.value : ing;
    });
    this.setState({ inputData });
  };
```

but it doesn't work so well...
I'm doing several inputs so I need it to be in the array for later extraction

Comment: Do you want inputData to be an array of strings or an array of objects?

Comment: It's really hard to tell the relation between `arr.input` and `inputData.inputArr`. Can you clarify?

Comment: arr input just has the input label/type/value it has nothing to do with the inputData, and I want input data to be an array of strings.

Comment: Thanks. That helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are doing is updating the value of your array at a particular index. You can simply update the index of the nested array and then set state to the value of an updated inputData.

```
handleChangeInp = e => {
    const index = Number(e.target.name)
    // upon research, changing inputData directly will mutate state
    const {inputData} = this.state;
    // so, spreading inputArr into a new variable creates a copy
    const inputArr = [...inputData.inputArr]
    inputArr[index] = e.target.value;
    // set state will full object data
    this.setState({ inputData: {id: inputData.id, inputArr}});
};
```

Comment: inputData.inputArr[index] = e.target.value; can you do that? inputData is the state you cant modify it like that, can you?

Comment: Yep, notice the curly braces around `inputData`. This means we destructured the state into a new variable, which we change and pass back to state.

Comment: This method mutates the original state.

Comment: Yep. Good catch. I"ll refactor